# set UIView to half the height of UITableViewCell content view using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have a `UITableViewCell` with a `UIView` as a subview. I want the height of the `UIView` (the dark blue rectangle) to always be equal to half of the `UITableViewCell` content view height.

I know I'm supposed to set a constraint between the `UIView` and the cell content view, but this option is disabled when I ctrl-drag between the `UIView` and the cell content view.

How can I achieve this using "Auto Layout" on a prototype cell inside a storyboard?

[image: the dark blue is the subview, I want its height to be equal to half the cell's height]

Comment: I had the same issue. Think you can only do this programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you set a bottom layout constraint and then edit it, you can change what part of a view it constrains to.

[image]